# Mounting a Mail Store that is in a Recovery Storage group On Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

If I have a production server with the Mail Store Foo in both the storage group companyName and the Recovery Storage Group, is it okay to Mount Foo in the RSG while it is mounted in companyName so I can extract some mailboxs from the recovery storage group?

Basically I am wonder if it is okay to mount it in both Production and the Recovery Storage Groups while the mail server is in production and the particular mail store is in production.

Reference:
"Once an RSG is restored into and mounted up you can connect to it with ExMerge and read out mailboxes into PST files for merging back into a 'live' store" --
[Test Restore of Exchange DBs with the MS-Exchange plugin of NetBackup 6](https://serverfault.com/questions/49728/test-restore-of-exchange-dbs-with-the-ms-exchange-plugin-of-netbackup-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  The RSG is a completely different storage group.  The fact that the databases might be named the same is not a problem.  If you follow Evan's advice in your reference, you'll be fine.

Comment: If only more people followed that general principle...  >smile<

Comment: HA, you showboater.